# Memory Usage With Spring Data MongoRepository Streams

Tags: java, mongodb, java-stream, heap-memory, spring-data-mongodb

I am currently working on a Spring Boot application that needs to interact with a MongoDB instance. One of my queries will potentially return a very large amount of data. I do not want to pull all of this data back at once. From my current understanding, I can specify a return type of `Stream<Type>` inside a `MongoRepository` as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface TypeRepository extends MongoRepository<Type, TypeId> {
    Stream<Type> findByValue(String value);
}
```

and then in a service method, do something like this:

```
Stream<Type> typeStream = typeRepository.findByValue("value");
typeStream.forEach(t -> {
    //do some stuff
});
```

In this example, how much data will actually be in memory at one time? I'm having a little trouble understanding how this works under the hood. Is there a batch size that is controlling how much data is sent back at once? How is that configured (on the MongoDB instance or the client)?

If there's anything I can add to this question to make it more suitable for this site, please let me know. This is my first question here. Conceptually, I understand what's going on. But at a lower level, I am lost. What does the network traffic look like and how is it being controlled?

Comment: So, I got some info from another person who pointed out that the limit to a BSON size in MongoDB is 16MB and because of that, the client would only receive 16MBs of data at a time while using a cursor to keep track of where it is in the processing of the Stream. So under the hood, the java Stream would only have 16MBs of data at once. Does this sound correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your should annotate your query with [@Meta](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Meta.html) and specify cursorBatchSize

```
@Meta(cursorBatchSize = 1000)
Stream<Type> findByValue(String value);
```

This trick makes sure that the whole stream is not fetched from the database in one go.